# dotnet data protection to database without using entity framework in .net5

Tags: c#, data-protection

I am able to implement data protection in .net with entity framework as suggested in
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-5.0

```
public class DataProtectionKeyContext : DbContext, IDataProtectionKeyContext
{
    public DataProtectionKeyContext(DbContextOptions<DataProtectionKeyContext> options)
        : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<DataProtectionKey> DataProtectionKeys { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<DataProtectionKey>()
            .ToTable("DataProtectionKey");
    }
}

services.AddDataProtection()
                .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new 
DirectoryInfo(_settings.DataProtectionLocation));
            services.AddDbContext<DataProtectionKeyContext>(o =>
            {
                o.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DataConnection"));
                o.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
                o.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
            }).AddDataProtection()
          .PersistKeysToDbContext<DataProtectionKeyContext>()
          .SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(7));
```

Is there any way to avoid entity framework in here ? I am using third party insight database adapter already in project. I am just trying to avoid multiple ORM's ? Please help ? I still want to save to database using custom adapter calls instead of ef dbcontext

Comment: It's just [a link away from the one you provided](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/non-di-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: I want to still save it to database because my application uses load balancing.